# Control max touch scroll speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll, tablet

I need to cap the speed a user is allowed to scroll on a tablet, therefore touch. I understand we're dealing with the 'scroll' event as well as 'touchstart', 'touchmove' and 'touchend'. I cannot use another plugin - so I was hoping to put a max speed on the scroll somehow. If a normal scroll is about '1' and a super fast scroll is about '4' then I want to be about to cap the scroll speed at '3'. 'preventDefault' and animating 'scrollTop' is choppy and will not work in this case.